# Regex expression - Remove lines that match multiple options

Tags: regex

I have some sample data below....

```
100.200.300.40 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:18:35 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 132189
100.200.300.40 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:18:35 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 106866
100.200.300.40 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:18:35 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 103461
100.200.300.40 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:19:10 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 106866
100.200.300.40 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:19:10 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 106866
100.200.300.40 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:19:10 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 106866
300.230.100.10 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:20:55 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 28017662
200.100.600.30 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:27:22 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 464787
200.100.600.30 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:27:22 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 463747
200.100.600.30 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:27:22 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 434485
200.100.600.30 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:27:54 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 330269
664.387.880.60 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:32:03 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 266372
664.387.880.60 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:32:34 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 176348
```

I am trying to use a regex expression to find the lines that match the following....

- Duplicate IP
- Duplicate Time
- Duplicate Filename

I then want to delete these lines so only one remains, there is a filesize at the end that differs slightly otherwise I could just remove duplicate lines.

I have managed to detect the IPs http://regexr.com?2vv5c  but thats as far as I have got, can anyone help?

**UPDATE**
In response to a comment left, out of the original data below....

```
100.200.300.40 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:18:35 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 132189
100.200.300.40 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:18:35 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 106866
100.200.300.40 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:18:35 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 103461
100.200.300.40 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:19:10 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 106866
100.200.300.40 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:19:10 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 106866
100.200.300.40 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:19:10 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 106866
300.230.100.10 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:20:55 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 28017662
200.100.600.30 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:27:22 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 464787
200.100.600.30 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:27:22 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 463747
200.100.600.30 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:27:22 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 434485
200.100.600.30 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:27:54 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 330269
664.387.880.60 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:32:03 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 266372
664.387.880.60 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:32:34 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 176348
```

The following should remain....

```
100.200.300.40 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:18:35 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 103461
100.200.300.40 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:19:10 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 106866
300.230.100.10 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:20:55 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 28017662
200.100.600.30 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:27:22 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 434485
200.100.600.30 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:27:54 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 330269
664.387.880.60 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:32:03 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 266372
664.387.880.60 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:32:34 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 176348
```

Comment: some examples for what should match and what should not match is always helpful.

Comment: Do you really need the filesize? If not, you could easily remove it, then use `sort` and `uniq` to filter out duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

looks like the desired result can be obtained using `sort -u`:

```
$ sort -k1,6 -u < test.txt 
100.200.300.40 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:18:35 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 132189
100.200.300.40 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:19:10 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 106866
200.100.600.30 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:27:22 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 464787
200.100.600.30 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:27:54 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 330269
300.230.100.10 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:20:55 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 28017662
664.387.880.60 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:32:03 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 266372
664.387.880.60 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:32:34 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 176348
```

The idea is to define fields 1-6 as key and ask sort to return a uniq list after sorting. it then returns only one uniq entry per key (ip+time+file). sort uniq's the list based on key definition and not on the entire line.

Answer (score 0):

So to know the duplicate lines in your sample data you could do following:

```
String subString = line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(" "));
```

Where `line` is a single line read from your sample data. Here `subString` is the `String` after removing the `filesize` which is at the end of each line of data. Now you can easily compare the  all such `subString` and remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Perl one-liner that does the job:

```
perl -ane '($id)=$_=~/^(.*) HTTP/;print unless exists $seen{$id};$seen{$id}=1;' logfile.log
```

It considers the string from the begining `^` until `HTTP` as a key for hash `%seen`.

If the key isn't present in the hash, prints the current line.

**output:**

```
100.200.300.40 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:18:35 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 132189
100.200.300.40 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:19:10 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 106866
300.230.100.10 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:20:55 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.0" 200 28017662
200.100.600.30 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:27:22 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 464787
200.100.600.30 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:27:54 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 330269
664.387.880.60 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:32:03 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 266372
664.387.880.60 - - [02/Feb/2012:12:32:34 +0000] temp/newfolder/resource/newitem.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 176348
```

Comment: Maybe a daft question but with this Perl version, how do I load the txt file with the data in first?

Comment: @fightstarr20: it's just a parameter, I've named it `logfile.log` in my answer. You've to do : `perl -ane 'all the perl code' file_to_be_treated`